# Cannot pass a value of an IG column to LOV parameter

Tags: parameter-passing, oracle-apex, lov, oracle-apex-20.2, interactive-grid

My problem is when trying to pass the value of an IG column to a parameter of LOV (based on Rest Data Source), the value did not passed.

However, I am able to pass the value of a page item successfully or a static value, but not the value of the IG column.

anyone can help?
Thanks,

[image: LOV Parameter Screenshot]

Comment: any help please ??

Comment: any help please, if anyone can advise.

Comment: Maybe try posting your question on [the Oracle APEX forum](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/categories/1application_express) to reach all the APEX experts.